# StateTrigger doesn't return to previous VisualState?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am trying to produce a 'determinate' ProgressRing for a Universal app under Windows 10 and am having problems using a StateTrigger - after being activated it does not return to the previous VisualState but instead returns to `null`. I would think that this is not the expected behaviour. The animation occurs correctly when triggered but not when it returns. It animates as expected when `...GoToState(..., "Running", ...)` is called from code, which also happens successfully during `OnApplyTemplate` anyway.

I have tried:

```
<VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
    <VisualTransition From="{x:Null}" To="Stopped" GeneratedDuration="0:0:1" />
    <VisualTransition From="Stopped" To="{x:Null}" GeneratedDuration="0:0:1" />
</VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
```

which (surprisingly) works during `To="Stopped"`, the same as the below code, but not during the reverse.

I'd like to have this working in XAML rather than from code. DotNet bug or my fault? And how do I fix it? Do I need to revert to the 'Running' state manually? The code, which appears within a ControlTemplate:

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="States">
    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:1" />
    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
    <VisualState x:Name="Running" />
    <VisualState x:Name="Stopped">
        <VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <StateTrigger IsActive="{Binding ShowPaused, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
        </VisualState.StateTriggers>
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PART_Indicator"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                             To="{ThemeResource ProgressBarIndicatorPauseOpacity}"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use [VisualStateManager.GoToState method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager.gotostate.aspx) in code-behind, your animation works. This is because in `GoToState` method, you have specified the state to transition to, so VisualStateManager system knows to perform which animation according to the [VisualTransition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.visualtransition.aspx).

But in XAML, you are using [StateTrigger class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.statetrigger.aspx) to specify when a particular [VisualState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstate.aspx) is to be applied. And while [StateTrigger.IsActive property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.statetrigger.isactive.aspx) is `true`, VisualStateManager system applies this `VisualState`. As `VisualStateManager` system knows the state to transition to, the animation will be performed. However, while `StateTrigger.IsActive` property is `false`, the state's modifications to the controls will be just removed, it won't trigger the changes between different `VisualState`s.

So in you sample, the `VisualTransition` to "Stopped" works, but when `StateTrigger.IsActive` is `false`, there is no animation. To fix this issue, we can set `VisualState.StateTriggers` in "Running" state with a `InvertBoolConverter` like following:

```
public class InvertBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var boolValue = (bool)value;
        return !boolValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var boolValue = (bool)value;
        return !boolValue;
    }
}
```

And in "Running" state:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Running">
    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
        <StateTrigger IsActive="{Binding ShowPaused, Converter={StaticResource InvertBoolConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
</VisualState>
```

Besides, in `VisualTransition`, the [From](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.visualtransition.from.aspx) value references the name of a state that is the current state. The [To](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.visualtransition.to.aspx) value references the name of a state that is the new state. And a `VisualTransition` can reference just a `From` state, just a `To` state, or both a `From` and `To` state. Omitting either `From` or `To` equates to any state. So if you do not want to set both a `From` and `To` state, you can just omit one of them rather than set it to `{x:Null}`.

```
<VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
    <VisualTransition To="Stopped" GeneratedDuration="0:0:1" />
    <VisualTransition From="Stopped" GeneratedDuration="0:0:1" />
</VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
```

Comment: Are the `VisualStateGroup.Transitions` expected to work without the `InvertBoolConverter`? How is that different to using the default `<VisualTranstion GeneratedDuration="0:0:1" />`? Neither work in my case without the `InvertBoolConverter` and both do with it. I still don't understand why the `InvertBoolConverter` is needed: shouldn't the `<VisualTransition From="Stopped" GeneratedDuration="0:0:1" />` take care of that?

Comment: @TimRawlinson In you case, `InvertBoolConverter` is required. VisualStateManager system needs to know the`VisualState` has changed, so it can perform animation according to the `VisualTransition`. If we don't set `StateTrigger` in "Runing", then there will be no change of `VisualState` when `ShowPaused` is `false`. This is because when `StateTrigger.IsActive` property is `false`,  it just remove the state's modifications to the controls and won't trigger the change of `VisualState`.