# WinUI 3: Why visual states defined for custom control didn't work?

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

I am trying to make a custom control on WinUI 3, it could validate user input and apply changes to control base on the result.

**Generic.xaml:**

```xml
<Style TargetType="controls:InputValidationHost">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:InputValidationHost">
                <StackPanel>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding InputControl}" x:Name="InputControl" />
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="CaptionText"
                        FontSize="{StaticResource CaptionTextFontSize}" />

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SetStyleByState">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unvalidated">
                                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                    <StateTrigger IsActive="{TemplateBinding IsUnvalidated}" />
                                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="CaptionText.Content"
                                        Value="{TemplateBinding UnvalidatedMessage}" />
                                    <Setter Target="CaptionText.Foreground"
                                        Value="{ThemeResource SystemColorGrayTextColor}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Passed">
                                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                    <StateTrigger IsActive="{TemplateBinding HasPassed}" />
                                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="CaptionText.Content"
                                        Value="{TemplateBinding PassedMessage}" />
                                    <Setter Target="CaptionText.Foreground" Value="Green" />
                                    <Setter Target="InputControl.Content.BorderBrush" Value="Green" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Error">
                                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                    <StateTrigger IsActive="{TemplateBinding HasError}" />
                                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="CaptionText.Content"
                                        Value="{TemplateBinding ErrorMessage}" />
                                    <Setter Target="CaptionText.Foreground" Value="Red" />
                                    <Setter Target="InputControl.Content.BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**InputValidationHost.cs:**

```cs
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation and Contributors.
// Licensed under the MIT License.

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using AkiraVoid.WordBook.Enums;
using AkiraVoid.WordBook.ViewModels;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup;

// To learn more about WinUI, the WinUI project structure,
// and more about our project templates, see: http://aka.ms/winui-project-info.

namespace AkiraVoid.WordBook.Controls
{
    [ContentProperty(Name = "InputControl")]
    public sealed class InputValidationHost : Control
    {
        public InputValidationHost()
        {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(InputValidationHost);
        }

        public Control InputControl
        {
            get => (Control)GetValue(InputControlProperty);
            set => SetValue(InputControlProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty InputControlProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(InputControl),
            typeof(Control),
            typeof(InputValidationHost),
            new(null));

        public InputValidationState State
        {
            get => (InputValidationState)GetValue(StateProperty);
            set => SetValue(StateProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty StateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(State),
            typeof(InputValidationState),
            typeof(InputValidationHost),
            new(InputValidationState.Unvalidated, StateChangedCallback));

        public IList<Func<object, bool>> Validators
        {
            get => (IList<Func<object, bool>>)GetValue(ValidatorsProperty);
            set => SetValue(ValidatorsProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValidatorsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(Validators),
            typeof(IList<Func<object, bool>>),
            typeof(InputValidationHost),
            new(new List<Func<object, bool>>()));

        public object ErrorMessage
        {
            get => GetValue(ErrorMessageProperty);
            set => SetValue(ErrorMessageProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ErrorMessageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(ErrorMessage),
            typeof(object),
            typeof(InputValidationHost),
            new(null));

        public object PassedMessage
        {
            get => GetValue(PassedMessageProperty);
            set => SetValue(PassedMessageProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty PassedMessageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(PassedMessage),
            typeof(object),
            typeof(InputValidationHost),
            new(null));

        public object UnvalidatedMessage
        {
            get => GetValue(UnvalidatedMessageProperty);
            set => SetValue(UnvalidatedMessageProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty UnvalidatedMessageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(UnvalidatedMessage),
            typeof(object),
            typeof(InputValidationHost),
            new(null));

        public bool HasPassed
        {
            get => (bool)GetValue(HasPassedProperty);
            set => SetValue(HasPassedProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty HasPassedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(HasPassed),
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(InputValidationHost),
            new(false));

        public bool HasError
        {
            get => (bool)GetValue(HasErrorProperty);
            set => SetValue(HasErrorProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty HasErrorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(HasError),
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(InputValidationHost),
            new(false));

        public bool IsUnvalidated
        {
            get => (bool)GetValue(IsUnvalidatedProperty);
            set => SetValue(IsUnvalidatedProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsUnvalidatedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(IsUnvalidated),
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(InputValidationHost),
            new(true));

        public event EventHandler<ValidationEventArgs> Validate;
        public event EventHandler<ValidationEventArgs> Validated;
        public event EventHandler<ValidationEventArgs> Passed;
        public event EventHandler<ValidationEventArgs> Error;
        public event EventHandler<ValidationEventArgs> StateChanged;

        public Func<Control, object> GetContent { get; set; }

        private void OnValidate()
        {
            Validate?.Invoke(this, new() { State = State });
        }

        private void OnValidated()
        {
            Validated?.Invoke(this, new() { State = State });
        }

        private void OnPassed()
        {
            Passed?.Invoke(this, new() { State = State });
        }

        private void OnError()
        {
            Error?.Invoke(this, new() { State = State });
        }

        private static void StateChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            var control = (InputValidationHost)d;
            control.SetValue(HasPassedProperty, control.State == InputValidationState.Passed);
            control.SetValue(HasErrorProperty, control.State == InputValidationState.Error);
            control.SetValue(IsUnvalidatedProperty, control.State == InputValidationState.Unvalidated);
            control.StateChanged?.Invoke(control, new() { State = control.State });
        }

        public void TriggerValidation(object content)
        {
            OnValidate();
            var isPassed = Validators.All(validator => validator(content));
            if (isPassed)
            {
                State = InputValidationState.Passed;
                OnPassed();
            }
            else
            {
                State = InputValidationState.Error;
                OnError();
            }

            OnValidated();
        }

        public void TriggerValidation()
        {
            TriggerValidation(GetContent(InputControl));
        }
    }
}
```

**My usage:**

```xml
<controls:InputValidationHost x:Name="InputValidation" ErrorMessage="Error" PassedMessage="Passed" UnvalidatedMessage="Unvalidated">
    <TextBox KeyUp="OnEnterPressed" />
</controls:InputValidationHost>
```

This should react to dependency properties `HasError`, `HasPassed`, `IsUnvalidated` and apply changes to `InputControl` and `CaptionText`. But when I use this control with a TextBox in it, all I got is a default TextBox without `CaptionText`. I'm sure I've set the `***Message`, and the state changes correctly.

You could find a [reproduction on GitHub](https://github.com/AkiraVoid/Test.WinUI3).

Answer (score 0):

To change [VisualStates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager.gotostate?view=winrt-22621) you need to call the `VisualStateManager.GoToState()` method:

```cs
VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Error", useTransitions: false);
```

**UPDATE**

I took a look at your repo and IMHO, you should use `GoToState()` instead of `StateTriggers`. `IsActive` will change the `VisualState` when is `True` but it won't change the `VisualState` back when is `False`. So, I guess it's better that you explicitly change the `VisualStates`.

This is a basic example:

**Generic.xaml**

```xml
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:VisualStateTests">

    <Style TargetType="local:CustomTextBox">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomTextBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxControl" />
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Red">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="TextBoxControl.Foreground" Value="Red" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Green">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="TextBoxControl.Foreground" Value="Green" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Blue">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="TextBoxControl.Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**CustomTextBox.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace VisualStateTests;

public sealed class CustomTextBox : Control
{
    public CustomTextBox()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomTextBox);
    }

    private TextBox? TextBoxControl { get; set; }

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        if (GetTemplateChild(nameof(TextBoxControl)) is TextBox textBoxControl)
        {
            TextBoxControl = textBoxControl;
            TextBoxControl.TextChanged += TextBoxControl_TextChanged; ;
        }
    }

    private void TextBoxControl_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateVisualState();
    }

    private void UpdateVisualState()
    {
        bool useTransitions = false;
        bool result = TextBoxControl?.Text.ToLower() switch
        {
            "red" => VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Red", useTransitions),
            "green" => VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Green", useTransitions),
            "blue" => VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Blue", useTransitions),
            _ => VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Normal", useTransitions),
        };
    }
}
```

In the case you need to use `StateTriggers` anyway, you can find a good sample code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38993204/2411960).

Comment: I tried what you said. Still nothing happens, although it returns true. I'm calling this method in `InputValidationHost.OnApplyTemplate`, is it the right place?

Comment: You call this every time you want to change the ``VisualState``.

Comment: Now I subscribed `StateChanged` event, so it will be triggered at every time the `State` property get changed. But there's still nothing happened. I'm wondering if the visual state manager cannot find the proper target to apply?

Comment: I uploaded a [reproduction](https://github.com/AkiraVoid/Test.WinUI3), which may be helpful.

Comment: You could see in `InputValidationHost.cs`, I actually called `VisualStateManager.GoToState()`, and by debugging it returns true, but still no changes applied.

Comment: And just before I removed state trigger from xaml, still did no effect.

Comment: In your ``VisualState.Setters`` you are setting ``Foreground``s for the ``ContentPrensenter``s not the ``TextBox`` that is in **MainWindow.xaml**. You should first comment out all ``VisualState`` related code and check which control, which property you want to change. Once you confirm that, you can bring the ``VisualStates`` back.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252501/discussion-between-andrew-keepcoding-and-akiravoid).